# Possibly silly question about strings and references in C#

Tags: c#

Good afternoon,

I'm sorry if this question is too silly, but I don't know much (almost anything) about .Net's memory management system, and I really need to clear up this doubt... I have a `Dictionary<String, Int32>` which I need to use, and now I need a tree whose nodes are labeled with the strings in that same dictionary. Since, of course, I don't want to store redundant information, how can I make sure the node's label point to the same references as the dictionary's keys?

Thank you very much,

Comment: Only tangentially related, but the reason that strings can always be passed around as references in .NET is because .NET string instances are immutable.  In C, it could be dangerous to pass around a char*, because other code might modify the buffer, assuming it was a copy.  You could protect against this somewhat by relying on 'const' modifiers to discourage modification.  In .NET, all strings are inherently 'const' and may be passed around freely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strings ARE reference types, so that would be the default unless you do something that breaks it.

For instance, for an asp.net page (which you didn't specify, I know), the string that's displayed at the client can't have the same reference as the string in the server's memory.

Answer (score 3):

You can use something like this:

```
TreeNode node = new TreeNode();
node.Text = dictionary.Keys[0];
```

It will be the same instance.

Comment: He says he wants to reference back to the dictionary too, so you should also set the Name property to the value.

Answer (score 1):

Since String is a reference type you must be very cautious when referring to dictionary entries using references to String objects. You obviously can, but it's sometimes impossible (just like different client-server references mentioned by Hans) If you know what you're doing, use references, but if not, you can always compare Strings by value ('Equals' method) to refer to dictionary elements.

Comment: The equality operator is overridden for String to perform by-value comparison.

Comment: Good point - 'Equals' method is just an example of comparing Strings by value, but you can also use '=='.

Comment: I'm not sure what issues you are referring to Piotr, can you give an example? Remeber that strings are immutable, so I'm not sure what problems you would find here.

Comment: 'Equals' also works poorly if your first instance is null. Something like `string x = null, y = ""; Assert.IsFalse(x.Equals(y));`

Comment: I'm referring to situations, when you compare actual references to Strings using Object's 'ReferenceEquals' method.

Comment: @Piotr - even if for some reason you decided to use ReferenceEquals to compare strings the fact the they are interned will actually stop you getting into trouble here (in recent CLR versions at least). Of course you shouldn't rely on string interning to save you, but then you really shouldn't be using ReferenceEquals on them either:-)

Comment: Well, the fact is that I can't really think of any other way to compare Strings by reference than by using ReferenceEquals. It's hard to deny that you can't rely on String interning, but please do refer to my answer - this is exactly what I said, you can compare Strings by reference only if you know what you're doing :)